# Applying a specific formula to a large matrix/data frame in R, in order to normalize my data

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, formula, diagonal

I have a large "distance matrix" (actually a 170x170 data frame in R), for example:

```
         A            B          C
A   0.198395022 0.314012433 0.32704998
B   0.314012433 0.262514533 0.318539233
C   0.32704998  0.318539233 0.211224133
```

I am trying to apply a specific formula (which I already have) to bring this variation into the scale of 0-1, as required for my statistical modeling. I am expecting to obtain something like this across the whole data frame (expected output, when applying the formula):

```
          A              B              C
A        1          0.846050953    0.825897603
B   0.846050953          1         0.822548469
C   0.825897603     0.822548469         1
```

So, I need to re-calculate each off-diagonal cell relative to the respective values by applying this *formula* in R:

[Formula here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GO64.png)

where **B** is the matrix of normalized values, **H** is my matrix/data frame, while *i* and *j* are the rows and columns of my matrix/data frame, respectively. It is supposed that this normalization procedure systematically replaces the diagonal (*i = j*) by 1.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible minimal example of the data and your best attempt at coding this.  Note the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a loop in order to replace each value according to your formula:

```
df <- data.frame(rnorm(3, 20,15), rnorm(3, 10,5), rnorm(3, 200,100))
df # Check out the results

for (i in 1:length(df)){   
    for (j in 1:nrow(df)){
       df[i,j] <- df[i,j]/((df[i,i]+df[j,j])/2)   
    } 
}
```

df ## Note that is done!